# how to align view to left and right properly in android layout with gravity or layout gravity

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, gravity

I am using the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cardview_shadow"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_find_previous_holo_dark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find_previous_holo_dark" />

        <ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/emoji_u1f33c" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/emoji_u1f33c" />
        </ViewFlipper>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_find_next_holo_dark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_find_next_holo_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want left arrow to the left & right arrow to the right & center layout to fill the center gap without giving exact width in dp, px etc but i m not able to achieve this layout. i need this type of layout most of the time[image]

Comment: why you dont wanna use layout gravity ??

Comment: where should i use layout gravity?

Comment: to the second linearLayout use `android:gravity="left|center_vertical"`

Comment: Give   `android:layout_weight =1` to the viewflipper and try if that fixes the issue.

Comment: thanks every one for your efforts , sunil sunny your code worked :D

Comment: @SandeepKumar I will put it as an answer with an explanation. You can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to give `android:layout_weight=1` to your `ViewFlipper` So that it can take rest of the space left by your other 2 image views (Will push both views to the sides since `ViewFlipper` is the middle view). A better explanation is given here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html check the Layout Weight section.